# On submission of 2nd form, first form is being validated - jquery validate

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

On submission of 2nd form, first form is being validated ,both forms are independent having separate submit buttons  and both are validated using jquery validator plugin.

here is my code :

```
$("#addVehicleForm,#discountInfoForm,#ihqform,#saveReturnForm,#driversForm").validate({
// stuff here

)}
```

`#saveReturnForm`,`#driversForm` these are the id's which i am passing in same `validator` `plugin method`.

I am trying to validate by click like this :

```
$("#my-submit-button-name").click(function(){
$(this).submit();
})
```

**Note : Both form has different submit button**

Comment: Why don't you put validations for each form seperately? Does the rules for all the forms are same?

Comment: i dont want to repeat highlight , errorplancement and other stuff @user1354678

Answer (score 0):

They are bound to the same event, so each form will be called. Instead use this:

```
$("#addVehicleForm,#discountInfoForm,#ihqform,#saveReturnForm,#driversForm").click(function(){
$(this).validate({  //Do your work here )}

)}

});
```

Comment: instead of `.click` you might need to use `.submit` event of `form` or `.on('submit,`

Comment: i am still not sure.. you are getting my question or not .. coz i simplly want to validate my one form but out 4 FORM two are on same page so both are getting validate

Comment: I believe their both being submitted because you're applying one validate method to all of them. You need to apply `validate` to them each individually. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I use jQuery Validate on almost every project. I wrote the following statement to run validation on every form. The key is the `each()` statement. The `each()` statement allows you to run `validate()` on each form element separately.

```
$('form').each(function(){

    $(this).validate({

        // stuff here

    });

});
```

Or in your case

```
$('#addVehicleForm, #discountInfoForm, #ihqform, #saveReturnForm, #driversForm').each(function(){

    $(this).validate({

        // stuff here

    });

});
```

Also, if you have custom buttons to submit the forms you can do this. But you should probably just use `<input type='submit' value='Submit' />`

```
$("#my-submit-button-name").on('click', function(){
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
})
```